# Ng-model and iOS credit card scanning

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, mobile-safari

Ng-model and iOS credit card scanning

I have a credit card form.  Each field looks something like this:

```
<input type=“text” ng-model = “cc.number”, ng-class = validClass('cc.number’)>
```

The `validClass` function returns `valid` or `invalid`, and it used for as-you-type validation.  It all works great- if you type a credit card that’s too long, or doesn’t pass Luhn validation, it lights up red.

When you hit ‘submit’, the code does credit card stuff with the values of `cc.number`, `cc.securityCode`, `cc.month`, and `cc.year`.

The problem comes when you use iOS’s [credit card scanner](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/scan-your-credit-card-instead-of-keying-in-number-for-purchases-in-ios-8/).  It’s a feature that, when you click on a credit card field on a website, lets you use your phone’s camera to scan your credit card.  It then parses that photo and puts the credit card number + expiration date into the form.  It’s pretty cool.

However, when iOS safari does this, it doesn’t seem to trigger ng-model to update.  The `validClass` function output doesn’t change based on the new input.  Worse yet, when the user submits the form, the updated value of `cc-number` doesn’t appear to have changed.

It’s frustratingly hard to debug this issue since this scanning feature isn’t available on the iOS simulator.  It’s also not available on a real iPhone when I point it to a local network address (e.g., my laptop).  It *appears* to only show up as an option on https sites, which makes it really hard to debug.

TLDR: iOS Safari’s “scan credit card” feature doesn’t update ng-model variables.  Does anyone have a good way to fix or work around this?

Comment: they probably fire an event when it changes, or you could use a plain old html _input_ event to update the model or at least call the validation routine...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can update the model when the user submits the form. You will need to name the form and the cc-number input so that you can refer to them from the scope.

```
<form name='creditCardForm'>
  <input name='cardNumber' ...>
```

Inside your submit handler ...

```
var cardNumber = $('[name="cardNumber"]').val()
$scope.creditCardForm.cardNumber.$setViewValue(cardNumber);
```

This will update the model and set the validity allowing you to cancel submission if its invalid.

```
if ($scope.creditCardForm.cardNumber.$invalid) {
  // cancel submit...
```